# How do I visualize the error in clustering algorithm and create a report in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, report, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I have grouped my data into say 3 clusters. So, each cluster has a group of similar users who bought similar items. Each cluster has a pattern. Now, not every user follows this pattern exactly as there are some errors in the model which can not be 100 percent accurate.

I  have to create a report in python, which contains the information for each user like

```
- userid
- How many items correctly matched the cluster pattern
- How many items did not match the cluster pattern due to error.
```

I have followed the basic approach with the below pseudo code:

```
foreach cluster
  get cluster pattern
  foreach user under this cluster
     compare if the itemid of user and itemid in the cluster are same
     save such items in a list
     or
     save in another list
```

Now since this is a huge result, I need to create a pdf of results in python and store it. How can I do this? Are there easy and alternate ways to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is Confusion matrix in sklearn module, actually I don`t know can you get from it any report, but you can visualize it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708865/confusion-matrix-for-clustering-in-scikit-learn) is conversation on this topic, and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) is official documentation, hope it will help you.

Comment: I checked this. But, I want to represent something very fundamental so that it is easy for a non-technical person to understand. Thanks for the reply, appreciate your help.